# Summing field in other rows conditionally

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have table in the form like below:

| Pilot | Leg | Duration | Takeoff |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | 1 | 60 | 9:00:00 |
| John | 2 | 60 | 9:00:00 |
| John | 3 | 30 | 9:00:00 |
| Paul | 1 | 60 | 12:00:00 |
| Paul | 2 | 30 | 12:00:00 |
| Paul | 3 | 30 | 12:00:00 |
| Paul | 4 | 60 | 12:00:00 |

And I am trying to figure out is a query to get the following:

| Pilot | Leg | Duration | Takeoff | LegStart |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | 1 | 60 | 9:00:00 | 9:00:00 |
| John | 2 | 60 | 9:00:00 | 10:00:00 |
| John | 3 | 30 | 9:00:00 | 10:30:00 |
| Paul | 1 | 60 | 12:00:00 | 12:00:00 |
| Paul | 2 | 30 | 12:00:00 | 13:00:00 |
| Paul | 3 | 30 | 12:00:00 | 13:30:00 |
| Paul | 4 | 60 | 12:00:00 | 14:00:00 |

So the 'LegStart' time is the 'TakeOff' time, plus the duration of prior legs for that pilot.

Now , to do this in SQL, I need to somehow add up the durations of prior legs for the same pilot. But for the life of me... I cannot figure out how you can do this because the pilots can have a variable number of legs, so joining doesn't get you anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try analytic [SUM](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#sum) `sum(duration) over (partition by pilot order by leg)`:

```
with mytable as (
  select 'John' as pilot, 1 as leg, 60 as duration, time '9:00:00' as takeoff union all
  select 'John', 2, 60, '9:00:00' union all
  select 'John', 3, 30, '9:00:00' union all
  select 'Paul', 1, 60, '12:00:00' union all
  select 'Paul', 2, 30, '12:00:00' union all
  select 'Paul', 3, 30, '12:00:00' union all
  select 'Paul', 4, 60, '12:00:00'
)
select
    *,
    time_add(takeoff, interval ifnull(sum(duration) over (partition by pilot order by leg ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING), 0) minute) as legstart
from mytable
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. One change is interval needs to subtract duration '(-duration + sum(duration) over (partition by pilot order by leg))'

Comment: Thanks :)
Also `ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING` can be used

Answer (score 2):

You can use a cumulative sum.  The trick is including this in the

```
select t.*,
       sum(duration) over (partition by pilot order by leg) as running_duration,
       datetime_add(takeoff,
                    interval (sum(duration) over (partition by pilot order by leg) - duration) minute
                   ) as leg_start
from t;
```

Note:  This assumes that `takeoff` is a `datetime`.

Comment: Thank you! Though I admit I still cannot get my head around OVER. How does it result in the sum of only prior rows adding? Is that the whole point of the over clause that the sum increments over each row it applies to?

Comment: @SectoKia . . . It is doing a cumulative sum which includes the current row (because of the `order by` in the `over` clause.  It then subtracts out the values in the current row.